# Splitting a string into multiple strings using regex

Tags: java, regex

I was working on a task to parse a cucumber feature string where I need to split string into 5 like the following.

```
String data = "calls 'create' using 'POST' on some uri";
```

I was implementing the basic split functionality multiple times (without any regex which is very tedious) to generate the data into the following.

```
String dataArray[] = {"calls '","create","' using '","POST", "' on some uri"};
```

I wanted to obtain the names of `dataArray[1]` and `dataArray[3]`. Is there a way to generate the above `dataArray` using regex and split or some other straight forward method?

Comment: So why `"calls '"` is one token but `"create'" is not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this?

```
String dataArray[] = data.split("'");
->
[calls , create,  using , POST,  on some uri]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which use Regex:

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
  String data = "calls 'create' using 'POST' on some uri";
  String[] dataArray = new String[2];
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("'[a-zA-Z]+'").matcher(data);
  int counter = 0;
  while (matcher.find()) {
    String result = matcher.group(0);
    dataArray[counter++] = result.substring(1, result.length() - 1);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
dataArray[0] --> create
dataArray[1] --> POST
```